# Trying to figure out a rotation issue in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, rotation

I am having trouble in fixing a problem with my iPad app.

I am loading a photo view controller when pressing a button on my main view controller.

In portrait mode the view controller loads fine, but when I load it in landscape mode my picture looks wrong:

[image: Screen Shot 2012-02-06 at 19.41.06.png]

I want it to look like:

[image: Screen Shot 2012-02-06 at 19.41.42.png]

I have narrowed down the problem to the following call:

```
- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    CGRect bounds = pagingScrollView.bounds;
    CGRect pageFrame = bounds;
    pageFrame.size.width -= (2 * PADDING);
    pageFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width * index) + PADDING;
    return pageFrame;
}
```

I've been trying to switch from `pagingScrollView.bounds` to `pagingScrollView.frame` but no go. `pagingScrollView.bounds` is a subview of my view. I just don't know how I can get it to recognize the orientation.

NOTE: When I rotate the device the problem fixes it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set the appropriate values for the `autosizingMask` property of your views.

If you are using a xib file, play around with the size inspector in interface builder (second right most tab on the Utilities panel in XCode 4.2)